# Google Email Login with OAuth Returns Invalid credentials for Chimlkat.Imap

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api, google-oauth, gmail-imap, chilkat

Trying to access a Google email account via IMAP with OAuth2 using the **Chilkat IMAP email component**.  I am receiving this from the server response...

> serverResponse: aaab NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials
> (Failure)

We are using VB.NET, and I am following the example at https://www.example-code.com/csharp/gmail_imap_login_oauth2.asp.  Connecting to imap.gmail.com using SSL and port 993.  I am setting the `Imap.AuthMethod = "XOAUTH2"` and using the AuthToken instead of the password.  The `Imap.Login(LoginName, AuthToken)` is where the error message is coming from.

I have enabled IMAP with the Gmail account, and I have enabled less secure apps.  I confirmed the right auth token is getting set for the password, and I have checked the API scope is properly set to https://mail.google.com/.  If I just try straight Login Name and Password the login is successful.

Not sure what else to check to figure out what is causing the **Invalid credentials** error.

Comment: Hi there @kencleary! I wasn't able to replicate your issue. I can see that you are using the third-party Chilkat library instead of the official [Google Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/). To prevent any misconfiguration on the Chilkat side, could you please try to connect to the Gmail API without it? You can use the [.NET quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Jacques.  I was able to get it to connect and read the folders following the .NET quickstart link.  I can take that back to Chilkat and see what they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem was found.

In the call to Login, the application was passing "Bearer " instead of just "" for the password:

Correct:
success = imap.Login("user@gmail.com","");

Incorrect:
success = imap.Login("user@gmail.com","Bearer ");

The access token is considered to be the password.  Chilkat adds the required "Bearer" string internally when composes the XOAUTH2 data sent to the IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem.  For the token I was setting it to "Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMDF.....", which is what we have set for the nSoftware component we use for calendar syncing.  I removed the "Bearer " part of the token and was able to login fine using the Chilkat IMAP Email Component".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this blog post to walk through the entire process:   https://cknotes.com/gmail-imap-oauth2-a-walkthrough/

1. At https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials, create Credentials (Client ID, Client Secret) and also define a Redirect URL
2. Code to get the initial OAuth2 token from your application.
3. Code to authentication in the IMAP protocol using OAuth2.
4. Code to refresh the token

I also uploaded some YouTube videos demonstrating 1 and 2.

Comment: We get the token and refresh it. Problem is trying to login to via the Chilkat IMAP email component with that token. We have been using the Chilkat component to login via IMAP with just standard login and password.  The only change we are doing is that if we are using the token we set the AuthMethod change the password to the token. Based on the Chilkat docs I thought that was the only changes to login with the auth token, right?